# Tensorflow: load images into memory only when needed

Tags: python, image, memory, tensorflow, load

I am using TensorFlow V1.7 with the new high-level Estimator interface. I was able to create and train my own network with my own dataset.

However, the policy I use to I load images just doesn't seem right to me.
The approach I have used so far (largely inspired by the MNIST tutorial) is to **load all images into memory since the beginning**
(here is a tiny code snippet to give you an idea):

```
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        filepath = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        # using OpenCV to read image
        images.append(cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
        labels.append(<corresponding label>)

    # shuffle samples and labels in the same way
    temp = list(zip(images, labels))
    random.shuffle(temp)
    images, labels = zip(*temp)

    return images, labels
```

This means that I have to load into memory all my training set, containing something like 32k images, before training the net. 
However since my batch size is 100 the net will not need more than 100 images at a time.

This approach seems quite weird to me. I understand that this way secondary memory is only accessed once, maximizing the performances; however, if my dataset was really big, this could overload my RAM, couldn't it?

As a consequence, I would like to use a lazy approach, only loading images when they are needed (i.e. when they happen to be in a batch).
How can I do this? I have searched the TF documentation, but I have not found anything so far.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's advised to use the [Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) module, which provides you the ability (among other things) to use queues, prefetching of a small number of examples to memory, number of threads and much more.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I really appreciate it!
Unfortunately, I am still stuck. 

I am now using a Dataset built from a generator, so each image is only read when the generator is asked to yield. 

However I don't understand how to pass this Dataset to my Estimator. More in detail, in my previous implementation I got an input function from tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(<my already read dataset>), and I passed this input function to the Estimator.train() method.

How can I do something like that with my already-computed Dataset?
I can't find any examples in the documentation :(

Comment: Yeah, would be nice if you could link to some examples. I'm looking through the TF docs and I'm not seeing how to do it. Looks like the keras.preprocessing.image classes are more useful than Dataset